# Preventing vulgarities in a textbox?

Tags: asp.net, implementation, spam-prevention

I  wish to validate a text box to detect vulgarities and prevent them in my .NET application.
Is there a guide example or tutorial that demonstrates how to implement this into your design that you can share with me or could the community share some code that I could use in my implementation for this?

Comment: I thought a vulgarity might have been some new design pattern the kids are using these days for a moment!

Answer (score 4):

Here you go: [Creating a "Bad Word Filter" functionality in ASP.NET w/C#](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/showtopic67129.htm)

Comment: Impressive list of vulgarities in the code attachment on that site!

Answer (score 1):

First, read up on the [Scunthorpe Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem).  There's no way to draw a clear line between good words and bad words.  And what about the prior administration here in the United States?  George **Bush** and **Dick** (Richard) Cheney.